# Can't send data context to template via Iron Router in Meteor

Tags: meteor

This is my router:

```
Router.route('/cource/:courcePath', {
  name: 'Cource_page',
  template: 'Cource_page',
  data() {
    return Cources.find({ courcePath: this.params.courcePath });
  }
});
```

Template:

```
<template name="Cource_page">
  <div class="container">
    {{#each cources}}
      <h1>{{courceTitle}}</h1>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

And helper:

```
Template.Cource_page.helpers({
  cources() {
    let courcePath = this.courcePath;
    console.log(courcePath);
    return Cources.find({ courcePath: courcePath });
  }
});
```

When I go to some page (http://localhost:3000/cource/my-new-cource, for example), no data rendering and I get `undefined` in the console (the output of template helpers). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the data in the render directive

```
Router.route('/post/:_id', function () {
  this.render('Post', {
    data: function () {
      return Posts.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
    }
  });
});
```

OR

you should subscribe to the data in the route:

```
Router.route('/cource/:courcePath', {
  name: 'Cource_page',
  template: 'Cource_page',
  subscriptions: function() {
    this.subscribe('courses', this.params.courcePath);
  }
});
```

Check the guide for more info:

http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/

Comment: PS: I'd recommend you learn Flow-Router which is becoming the de-facto router for Meteor, and is much more flexible. I built my app on Iron-Router and had to rewrite a lot of stuff when I starting having issues with Iron-Router (like random re-render...)  https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router

Answer (score 0):

When you provide the data context in your i-r route you don't need the helper. Try:

```
Router.route('/cource/:courcePath', {
  name: 'Cource_page',
  template: 'Cource_page',
  data() {
    return Cources.find({ courcePath: this.params.courcePath });
  }
});

<template name="Cource_page">
  <div class="container">
    {{#each this}}
      <h1>{{courceTitle}}</h1>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```